# Vim airline unicode spacing issues

Tags: vim, unicode, spacing

So after setting up [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) for vim on osx using iTerm2, I have this spacing issue for the unicode left separator.

[image: Screenshot of spacing issue.]

Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: I believe you may have to try a different font, or adjust the font size in iTerm.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.